# Excel VBA If this is true End otherwise do this

Tags: excel, vba, xlsm

How would I write a VBA statement that basically says if "A1" says "Yes" ignore the rest of the my code and End otherwise go to the next line.

Thanks

I cant seem to get it to work, i cant get it to skip the rest of the code

Comment: Show us your code, I'm sure it'll clarify exactly what's wrong with it! (you can [edit] your post any time :)

Comment: `If Range("A1") = "Yes" Then Exit Sub` (assuming that's what you want to exit - maybe you want to exit a loop instead, you did not include any code for context)

Answer (score 0):

Easy... ;-)

[image]

```
Sub YesICan()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Selection
    Dim cl As Range

    For Each cl In rng.Cells
        If LCase(cl) = "yes" Then
            cl.Offset(, 1) = "Hi There!"
        Else
            cl.Offset(, 1) = ""
            'do other stuff
        End If
    Next cl


End Sub
```